# Spring Boot initialize new instance for nested configuration binding when there are no corresponding nested key/value pairs in application.properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-config

I have a configuration class like below. All of fields in the inner class `OptionalServiceConfigs` has a default value as annotated using `@Value` as shown in below.

Sometimes in my `application.properties` file, it **does not** have a single `service` prefixed property. In that case, we want to have loaded an `OptionalServiceConfigs` instance with its default field values.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myconf")
public class MyConfigs {

   // ... rest of my configs

   @Value("${service:?????}") // what to put here, or can I?
   private OptionalServiceConfigs service;   // this is null

   // In this class all fields have a default value.
   public static class OptionalServiceConfigs {

       @Value("${mode:local}")
       private String mode;

       @Value("${timeout:30000}")
       private long timeout;

       // ... rest of getter and setters
   }

   // ... rest of getter and setters
}
```

But unfortunately, the `service` field is `null` when it is accessed using its getter method. Because spring boot **does not** initialize an instance of it when there is no property keys found with prefixed `myconf.service.*` in my `application.properties` file.

**Question:**

How can I make `service` field to initialize to a new instance along with its specified default field values when there are no corresponding prefixed keys in properties file?

I can't imagine a value to put in annotation `@Value("${service:?????}")` for `service` field. 
Nothing works, tried, `@Value("${service:}")` or `@Value("${service:new")`

Comment: And when you *do* put a value in application.properties, it works? What value do you put in there?

Comment: Remove `@Value` (you shouldn't combine `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Value`!). Just create a new instance of `OptionalServiceConfigs` in your class and set the default values as regular values. If they aren't set the defaults apply then, if they are set, Spring Boot will overwrite it.

Comment: @rustyx If I put `myconf.service.timeout=10000` or `myconf.service.mode=remote` or both, then `service` field is getting initialized with all of field default+specified values. The `service` field does not get initialized when I don't have any of properties.

Comment: @M.Deinum Actually, what you are saying is my Plan-B! :D But I am curious to know is there any spring way of doing it? I mean, can I say spring to initialize a new instance with default values in case I don't have any of nested property keys, rather than initializing and setting it myself. And also it differs from how I load my other nested configurations.

Comment: No there isn't because you shouldn't be mixing `@ConfigurationProperties` and `@Value`. The way I described is also the way used internally in Spring Boot to define defaults and have binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [@M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum)'s advice, did some changes to configuration class. I am a newbie to Spring and it seems I have misunderstood how Spring works behind-the-scenes.

1. First I removed all `@Value` annotation from inner class (i.e. `OptionalServiceConfigs`), and as well as `service` field in `MyConfigs` class.
2. Then, initialized all inner class fields with their default values inline.
3. In the constructor of `MyConfigs`, I initialized a new instance of `OptionalServiceConfigs` for the field `service`.

By doing this, whenever there is **no** `service` related keys in my `application.properties` a new instance has already been created with default values.

When there is/are `service` related key/s, then Spring does override my default values to the specified values in `application.properties` *only* the field(s) I've specified.

I believe from Spring perspective that there is no way it can know in advance that a referencing field (i.e. `service` field) would be related to the configurations, when none of its keys exist in the configuration file. That must be the reason why Spring does not initialize it. Fair enough.

**Complete solution:**

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "myconf")
public class MyConfigs {

   // ... rest of my configs

   private OptionalServiceConfigs service;

   public static class OptionalServiceConfigs {

       private String mode = "local";

       private long timeout = 30000L;

       // ... rest of getter and setters
   }

   public MyConfigs() {
      service = new OptionalServiceConfigs();
   }

   // ... rest of getter and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try such a structure which works for me quite fine:

```
@Data
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "gateway.auth")
@Configuration
public class AuthProperties {

@NotNull
private URL apiUrl;

@Valid
@NotNull
private Authentication authentication;

@Data
public static class Authentication {
    @NotNull
    private Duration accessTokenTtl;
    @NotNull
    private String accessTokenUri;
    @NotNull
    private String clientId;
    @NotNull
    private String clientSecret;
    @NotNull
    private String username;
    @NotNull
    private String password;
    @Min(0)
    @NonNull
    private Integer retries = 0;
   }
}
```

Important is to have getters and setters in order to enable Spring to postprocess ConfigurationProperties, I am using Lombok (@Data) for this.

please see here for more details:

[Baeldung ConfigurationProperties Tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)

Comment: `@NotNull` caused to fail immediately as it is always null when there are no keys (`gateway.auth.authentication` in your case) in application properties file. I want to make it automatically initialize to a new instance.

Comment: You would configure defaults and specific value and overwrite getters for specific values to return either specific or default value.